# Array on JS iterate just once, not showing the info the second time it's clicked on

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, for-loop, mobile

I created a modal to show info on an onClick event. The click creates an array with data extracted from the cards it's clicked, and shows it on a modal. The first time everything is ok, but the second time it doesn't. Don't know what's happening, asked some  friends, none of them knows what's happening.
I'm sharing just a bit of the code. The whole page is on this repository on github: https://github.com/santfernandez/artemtalleresoriginal

HTML

```html
    <section id="talleres" class="talleres-container">
                <div class="talleres">
                    <h2>TALLERES</h2>
                    <div class="talleres-flex">
                        <div class="card card-m" onclick="justChecking(event)">
                            <picture>
                                <source media="(max-width: 990px)" srcset="./img/img-musica-small.jpg" class="img-talleres">
                                <source media="(min-width: 990px)" srcset="./img/img-musica-large.jpg" class="img-talleres">
                                <img class="img-talleres" src="./img/img-musica-large.jpg" alt="">
                            </picture>
                        </div>
                    </div>
              </div>
            </section>
            <div id="modal"></div>
```

JS

```js
    const justChecking = (event) => {
      if (screen.width <= 479) {
        const h3Content = event.currentTarget.querySelector('.h3').innerText;
        const h3 = document.createElement('h3')
        const pContent = event.currentTarget.querySelectorAll('.p');
        const pArray = [...pContent]
        const p = document.createElement('p')
        let text = '';
        // const pForEach = () => {
        //   let c = pArray.map(element => text = element.textContent);
        //   console.log(c ,'asdgfgfdg')
        // }
        // console.log('asdasd',pForEach())
        // console.log(text)
        const modalContent = document.createElement('section');
        const modalDialog = document.createElement('div');
        const modal = document.createElement('div');
        const modalDiv = document.getElementById('modal')
        h3.textContent = h3Content;
        
        modalContent.className = 'modal-content';
        modalDialog.className = 'modal-dialog';
        modal.className = 'modal is-visible';
        modalContent.appendChild(h3);
        // realizamos un for para recorrer el array y repetir la creacion de contenido un por cada elemento que encuentra
        for (let i = 0; i < pArray.length; i++) {
            const element = pArray[i];
            console.log(element)
            modalContent.appendChild(element)
            ;
          }
        console.log(pArray)
        modalDialog.appendChild(modalContent);
        modal.appendChild(modalDialog);
        modal.onclick = function() {
          modalDiv.removeChild(modal);
        }
          modalDiv.appendChild(modal);
      }
      else{
        console.log('funciona');
      };
    };
```

Comment: Any console errors?

Comment: None, it just shows an empty array after the first print on the modal.

Comment: Print pContent right after assigning it and let us know what you see in both cases.

Comment: I just had to add clone the node I was receiving from the onClick, it solved the problem